# Please help me understand this python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a=10    
b=20    
res = (_("result is : %(first) , %(second)") %{'first' : a,'second' : b})    
print res
```

Could anyone explain the functionality of above code?

Comment: Do you happen to have a `from gettext import something as _` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Why is everybody downvoting this? It seems like a legitimate question

Comment: @jamylak: Because there is too little context here to determine what the question is *about*. Is it about the `_()` call, or about the `'' % {}` string formatting? (I didn't vote, but the OP has *not* explained what the problem is, really).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree that it's too localized but it doesn't need a downvote and OP deserves an answer since the problem is simple enough

Comment: i want to understand the (_( part .

Comment: Is this Django perhaps? They use `gettext`, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_` is usually the redefinition of the `gettext` module, which is a set of tools that helps translating text into many languages: As shown here:

```
import gettext
gettext.bindtextdomain('myapplication', '/path/to/my/language/directory')
gettext.textdomain('myapplication')
_ = gettext.gettext
# ...
print _('This is a translatable string.')
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html

Otherwise, when you use `%(name)s` in a string, it's for string formatting. It means: "format my string with this dictionary". The dictionary in this case is: `{'first' : a,'second' : b}`

The syntax of your string is wrong though - it's missing the `s` after the brackets.

Your code basically prints: result is : 10 , 20
If you fix the missing `s`

For further information, you can read this: [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't work :

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 20
>>> res = (_("result is : %(first) , %(second)") %{'first' : a,'second' : b})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

But otherwise, this seems like a simple text formating, using old style formating with maps.

You first write a string containing arguments using the syntax `%argument` and then you give it a map containing this argument's value using this syntax :

`"This is an argument : %argument " % {'argument' : "Argument's value" }`

Try to avoid using this and use `format` instead as it's easier to understand, more compact and more robust:

`"This is an argument : {} and this one is another argument : {} ".format(arg1, arg2)`